# Can't run heroku rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

My application works perfectly on development, but when i try to serve it on Heroku, i get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "games" ("id" serial primary key, "title" character varying, "image" character varying, "description" character varying, "user_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_de9e6ea7f7"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
)
```

That error appears when i try to run `heroku rake db:drop, heroku rake db:reset, heroku rake db:migrate`.

this is my DB schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170305021159) do

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "game_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["game_id"], name: "index_comments_on_game_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "image"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_games_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

This is my env:

```
Rails version             5.0.2
Ruby version              2.3.1-p112 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
RubyGems version          2.5.1
Rack version              2.0.1
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
```

This project was created with rails 4 and later updated to rails 5.

How can i migrate my db in Heroku ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried to run `heroku rake db:schema:load` to directly load your schema on heroku?

Comment: heroku rake db:schema:load, Worked correctly; any idea of what could be happening ? @Iceman

Comment: Goo,d I made an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way of doing this is to run

```
heroku rake db:schema:load
```

as it loads the working schema from your development database unto your production server. Using migrations is not recommended, this is from the official guides

> Migrations, mighty as they may be, are not the authoritative source
>   for your database schema. That role falls to either db/schema.rb or an
>   SQL file which Active Record generates by examining the database. They
>   are not designed to be edited, they just represent the current state
>   of the database.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Comment: Actually, I think you want `heroku run rake db:schema:load`. I believe the `heroku rake` syntax is deprecated.